# how to know current environment is content.js or background.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I include a script file both in content environment and background environment ,I want to judge the current envir in the code . I try to do this by accessing the module which is restricted in content environment .  like that

```
    if(chrome.tabs){
    // in background environment because tabs module cannn't use in content.js
    }else{
    // in content environment
    }
```

but that did't work , any suggestions, I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are many ways to check this.

One way is to check the location of the current page using `window.location`. If it begins with `chrome-extension://` you know that you're in the background page or on the popup.

You can use also check for `chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxx/_generated_background_page.html` in the URL to make sure you are on the background page, unless you have specified a HTML file for your background page.